# how can I control a gui installer with powershell or python

Tags: python, user-interface, powershell, installation

I want to automate the installation of a number of programs (on windows), using either Python or Powershell (I guess it will be easier using Powershell?). Unfortunately those programs don't have silent installers, so I have to install them using the GUI installers.
What would be the best way to access the text-boxes and buttons inside the GUI?

I saw this [post](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/01/10/provide-input-to-applications-with-powershell/) explaining how do do that with "SendKeys", but:

a. It seems like it would only work with windows containing only one text-box.

b. It doesn't seem like a robust way (i.e. another application might pop up between invoking the installer and sending the input)

Is there a better way to do that?

Thanks!